# How can you constrain elements of a UITableViewCell to the bottom of the navigation bar?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a translucent and clear navigation bar to show the full image of a table view header while still having navigation buttons. However, I want to constrain an item in the UITableView header to the bottom of the clear navigation bar and it is not working properly.

***I currently constrain the table view to the very top with a negative padding value of the navigation bar height***

I have tried getting the navigation bar height and passing that to the UITableView cell class but it does not work even after tableView.reload()

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell") as! TopCell
        let navHeight = CGFloat(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0))
        cell.navBarHeight = navHeight
        return cell
    }
```

---

```
var navBarHeight: CGFloat = 0

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(icon)
        icon.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: (CGFloat(navBarHeight + 10)), paddingLeft: 50, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }
```

The current result constrains the icon to the very top.

Answer (score 0):

Access view controller with navigation bar and get height from there in cell class

```
let mainVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
let navBarHeight = CGFloat(mainVC.navigationBar.frame.height) + CGFloat(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)
```